# printing linked list from beginning

Tags: c, linked-list

I got the code from wikipedia for linked list ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list ).

But it prints the result in reverse order (5 4 3 2 1 ). How to make this to print from beginning ( 1 2 3 4 5).

Comment: Which code sample are you looking at?  I think you're misunderstanding the insertion, not the printing.

Comment: That is a long page with lots of code examples. Post the specific routine you are having trouble with.

Comment: Considering the question's tagged "C", the C code sample would be the one to look at.

Comment: Example on wiki is misleading: list_add is actually "insert at the beginning" and not "addition to end" as intuition would suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the following example:

```
/****************************************************************/
/*  Function: Add an element to our list                        */
/*                                                              */
/*   Parameters: **p is the node that we wish to insert at.     */
/*               if the node is the null insert it at the beginning    */
/*               Other wise put it in the next space                   */


LLIST *list_add(LLIST **p, int i)
{
    if (p == NULL)           /*checks to see if the pointer points somewhere in space*/
        return NULL;

    LLIST *n = malloc(sizeof(LLIST));   /* creates a new node of the correct data size */
    if (n == NULL)
        return NULL;

    n->next = *p; /* the previous element (*p) now becomes the "next" element */
    *p = n;       /* add new empty element to the front (head) of the list */
    n->data = i;

    return *p;
}
```

Elements are being added to the *beginning* of the linked list when you call `list_add`.  This is for efficiency reasons; you don't have to transverse the entire linked list to insert an element (which you would have to do if you wanted to append).

To print in reverse, you can use recursion, build your own stack (which is the blind man's recursion), or recreate the list in reverse.  A recursive version:

```
void list_print_reverse(LLIST *n)
{
    if (n == NULL)
    {
        printf("list is empty\n");
        return;
    }

    if (n->next != NULL)
    {
        list_print_reverse(n->next);
    }

    printf("print %p %p %d\n", n, n->next, n->data);
}
```

Comment: Thank you :)
And in the list_remove, it removes only the first occurence, what I have to do to remove all the occurences of the data?

Comment: you have to go through whole list and remove 1 by 1

Comment: //(which you would have to do if you wanted to append).

Sorry, I am beginer in pointers :(. If I want to append how to do that?

Comment: @Guru, Find the last element in the linked list, and assign the new node to `last_element->next`.  (Make sure the new node's `->next` is `NULL`!)

Comment: As I said I am not good at pointers. Can you please explain it detail that how to traverse to the last element?

Comment: `while(n->next != NULL) { n = n->next; }`

Answer (score 1):

I assume you're talking about the C implementation in "Language support".

It doesn't print in reverse order. It's because elements are inserted in the head of the list, so inserting 1, 2, 3 would result in a list that contains 3, 2, 1.

This is because the list is represented by its head, so it's faster inserting at the head than the tail. To insert at the tail you would have to go through the entire list. This makes insertion O(n) instead of O(1).

Seeing as this is a singly-linked list, you cannot print it in the other order because you can only step forward.

Comment: If I want to insert at O(n) How to do that? I am not good at pointers :(

Comment: @Guru: Loop through the list until you get to the point where the next element is a `NULL` pointer. Then just set that pointer to the element you're trying to insert.

Comment: To note: This is a LIFO (last in first out) setup instead of FILO (first in last out) setup. A bit like a stack of plates. The plate at the bottom has to wait for the others to be popped off before being accessible.

Comment: @Paul Dragoonis: When you say FILO, you mean FIFO.  FILO is the same as LIFO

Comment: Yes i do. I think of it in my head as either "a stack" or "a queue". Either a stack of plates, or queuing at a shop.

Answer (score 0):

That is because the way the list is constructed.

To print it in reverse, just recurse to the last entry and print from there.

Comment: Just pray the list isn't too long, or you overflow the stack.

Comment: I would be more worried if you are printing out 25 000 or more entries...  :)

Answer (score 0):

The order in which list is being printed is the order in which elements are present in the list. You can print it in reverse order (i.e in order in which elements were inserted) using recursion. following code will print the list in reverse order

> void list_print(LLIST *n)   {
>       if (n == NULL)
>       {
>           printf("list is empty\n");
>           return;
>       }
>   }
>
> void print_recursive(LLIST *n)   {
>       if(n->next==NULL)
>           printf("%d\n",n->data);
>       else
>           print_recursive(LLIST n->next);
>   }

Comment: Super, you just 'copied' the previous answer! Why didn't I think of that?

Comment: i didnt copy it. when i started typing this answer wasnt here.

Answer (score 0):

I have this program which prints a string in reverse using recursion. Can you please use your linked list as input to it?

```
void reversePrint(char *str)
{
if(*str == '\0')
return;
reversePrint(str+1);
printf("%c",*str);
}
int main()
{
char *input;
input = malloc(10);
strcpy(input,"wolfrevo");
reversePrint(input);
}
```

I can change it myself, but hope it will be a nice excercise for you.

**Hints:**

1. Pass linked list instead of string // Change the protype too
2. Check for list being NULL
3. Recurse by pass next element of Linked list
4. Print the data inside list instead of string

Answer (score 0):

You can also try a double-linked list. Basically, you have an additional pointer to the previous element

```
typedef struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;     /* pointer to next element in list */
    struct node *previous; /* pointer to previous element in list */
} node;

typedef struct list {
    node *head;            /* first element in list */
    node *tail;            /* last element in list */
} list;
```

You can then print the list from the head and/or from the tail.